# Some Navigation Graph Actions Are Not Resolved

Tags: android, kotlin, android-safe-args, navgraph

I have multiple nav graphs in my projects each has multiple actions defined.

Lately, I am getting this error while **Building** the app preventing me from generating APK
`Unresolved reference: action...`

This error appears in some actions only (4 exactly), not all of them. And I can't figure out why.

```
findNavController().navigate(MyAppClassDirections.actionTasksToFooClassDetails(
   item.requestNumber,
   item.id.toString(),
   ActionCode.Inbox //Enum
))
```

And this is the action declaration in NavGraph

```
<action
  android:id="@+id/action_tasks_to_foo_class_details"
  app:destination="@id/my_other_dest"
  app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
  app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right"
  app:popEnterAnim="@anim/pop_enter"
  app:popExitAnim="@anim/pop_exit">
    <argument
       android:name="requestNumber"
       app:argType="string" />

    <argument
       android:name="id"
       app:argType="string" />

    <argument
       android:name="actionCode"
       app:argType="com.myapp.data.ActionCode" />
</action>
```

**Note:** Same action like this is declared several times in the graphs and are working fine.
Some how this specific declaration is causing the issue.

**My conclusion so far:** I don't think it is a code error. However, it is most likely a cache issue or something wrong with the navigation library.

I am using **navigation:2.5.3**

**What I have done:**

- Invalidate cache and restart Android Studio (Several Times).
- Clean/Rebuild project (Several Times).
- Removed the class and added it again.
- Renamed the action's id.

Nothing worked... :(

Any idea how to fix this??

Comment: Change version of library?

Comment: @tomerpacific.. To what?

Comment: 2.5.3 is the latest so maybe try an older one?

Comment: are you trying to use string instead of enum for sending your data?

Comment: @ShiftDelete... No I am using Enum already 'ActionCode'

Comment: can you try and see what happened? I guess it is a parcel error

Comment: I have facing the same issue. Only when I tried to add anything in Navigation graph.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to add some default value to enum that match with provided one as mentioned in documentation

So as per your code you can do like this

```
<argument
       android:name="actionCode"
       android:defaultValue="Inbox"
       app:argType="com.myapp.data.ActionCode" />
```

Please check this link
https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#supported_argument_types

Comment: Sorry, Didn't work